# How can I get the version number of my installed Nvidia driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, version

How can I get the version number of my Nvidia driver in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal and type this:

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

You'll see something similar to this:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  260.19.06  Mon Sep 13 06:35:06 PDT 2010
GCC version:  gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5)
```

The version number in my case is `260.19.06`